# Is it possible to get the result of applying the geometry node modifier on a curve object?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to apply the geometry node modifier so I could do some weight painting on the resulting mesh. When I try to do it right now, it gives me an error telling me to convert the curve to a mesh first. I am guessing that Blender has a limitation in that it can't do it on its own automatically.

The geo node program uses spline factors internally, so converting the object to a mesh first is not an option for me...though it never occurred to me until now that I could start with a mesh of edges and convert to a curve as the first step, and then the rest of the steps would work. Still, curves have direction, tilt and radius, which would get lost if I started with a faceless mesh.

Is there a way to do what I asked in the title directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ⇾ **Visual Geometry to Mesh**.

Comment: Nope. While that does give me the curve that was turned into a mesh, it leaves out the instances that were distributed on the faces,  Maybe I need to realize them first?

Comment: Yeah, I needed to realize the instances. That did the trick. Thanks.